# Can I use a custom widget as a view in a model-based QListView?

Tags: qt, qt5

I would like to render a series of complex data in a scrollable list using Qt5. Since the source of the data is a timeline, I'd like to load it lazily --- that is, I would like to use the features of `QAbstractItemModel` to load data on demand. The views will be read-only.

Can I use a custom widget to display data in each cell of the list?

So far I've seen some suggestions:

- use `QAbstractItemView->setIndexWidget()`; however, because I'd like to load the data lazily, it seems needlessly expensive to create and set widgets for all indices, before the data is loaded.
- use `QAbstractItemView->setItemDelegate()` with a custom `QStyledItemDelegate` that overrides `paint()`. The result looked good, but the widgets were simply rendered, and not interactive (couldn't select text, etc).

Comment: That can be done easily using QML, but I don't know about Qt Widgets. Looks like others ran into this issue before: https://forum.qt.io/topic/13165/how-to-make-qlabel-text-selectble-in-qstyleditemdelegate-type-of-class

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `QGraphicsScene` or even with `QScrollArea` + your custom widgets. It is not necessary to use `QAbstractItemModel` everywhere.

If you will use custom widgets for each model item you, probably, will have performance and interactivity problem.

Ofc, you can write a custom delegate, but delegates with interactivity is very complex topic - it is necessary to handle mouse events manually, draw a selection, etc.

Comment: In your first suggestion, then I'd have to reimplement item selection manually, correct? As for #2, would you please explain this in more detail?

Comment: What details do you need? How to create a new widget? Or how to add a widget to an existing `QScrollArea`?

Comment: You answer says "you, probably, will have performance and interactivity problem." What problems do you mean?

Comment: I mean, that widgets, that are used as delegates will not have hover/pressed animations in some cases. And if you will have a lot of widgets - you may have visible UI lags. A lot of means 100 - 100000, depends on widget complexity.